# Compare values from now and 2 hours ago and how the difference

Tags: grafana, influxdb

As can be see from the chart below we have a sensor that is recording pressure. The pressure has dropped 2 points within 2 hours. If this drops 2 points within 2 hours, this causes us some problems. I would like to create a query that compares the values from now and 2 hours in the past and display the difference. How can i achieve this in influx query language?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are best off using a derivative and depending on the exact response, either derivateive or non negative to see rate of change:

[InfluxDB Functions - Derivative](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#non-negative-derivative)

Youd set the unit to 2h (it defaults to 1s)

Thanks